# Can't run an SQL statement from within a C extension

Tags: c, database, postgresql

I have a C extension (code below) in which I'm trying to get access to a database but I'm getting the following error:

`FATAL:  cannot read pg_class without having selected a database at character 15`

How to get around this issue? I couldn't find out how to specify the database in the SPI API.

Similar code if run through a trigger (calling a function that accesses the same database) works just fine - obviously the database is implicit in this case.

Code follows:

```
static void my_function(XactEvent event, void *arg) {
char   sql[512];
switch(event) {
case XACT_EVENT_COMMIT:
  if(SPI_connect() == SPI_OK_CONNECT)
  {
    snprintf(sql, sizeof(sql), "SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable;");
    if (SPI_OK_SELECT == SPI_execute(sql, true, 0))
    {
      // Rest of code...
    }
  }
```

Thanks,

D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database should always be implicit, since SPI is only meant to be used by C functions called from a database session. See the [example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi-examples.html).

How do you execute this code?

Comment: I register this as follows: RegisterXactCallback(my_function,NULL) in _PG_init(). It is then called on XactEvent's (COMMIT, ROLLBACK).

Comment: Forgot to mention that it is linked to PostgreSQL (that is, the function is part of the db server).

Comment: This is correct answer. Can't call SPI commands that run against a database outside a database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SPI, but do you just need to send "use myDatabaseName;" first?